# Question on SocketAsyncEventArgs (SAEA)

Tags: c#, sockets

I've implemented an asynchronous socket connection and have it communicating with a client successfully. The problem I'm currently having is when sending packets to the client on a timer independent to the protocol that's defined.

Every time I call **SAEA.AcceptSocket.SendAsync(...)** I get the exception:
*System.InvalidOperationException: "An asynchronous socket operation is already in progress using this SocketAsyncEventArgs instance."*

I did some testing and cannot seem to call **SAEA.AcceptSocket.SendAsync(...)** immediately one after the other. Is this the way SAEA has been designed or am I be doing something wrong in my code that's causing the exception to be raised?

I've spent a bit of time googling this but can't seem to find any answers. If someone could help me or atleast point me in the right direction it'd be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a single operation can be pending per instance of `SocketAsyncEventArgs`. You either need to wait for the currently pending operation to complete OR simply use a unique instance of `SocketAsyncEventArgs` per send.

Comment: How do you create a unique instance when the SocketAsyncEventArgs is created from the completion of an Accept, thus really having one SocketAsyncEventArgs per client?

Comment: You create a SocketAsyncEventArgs for your initial acceptAsync call, pass it to that and eventually, when the call completes, you get it back... You can then either reuse it or create a new one for the next thing async operation you need to do...

Comment: Thanx Len your suggestion lead me to the right track. 

I did use a unique instance of a SocketAsyncEventArgs and used the socket from another SocketAsyncEventArgs to send to the same client. The exception I got was because a SocketAsyncEventArg was used concurrently but it seems to be ok to use the same AcceptSocket  between two or more SocketAsyncEventArgs.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you send the message over, it will try to send or wait till timeout or error.
What happen to u might be you are still processing the previous message and u tried to send again, using the same SocketAsyncEventArgs. If the SocketAsyncEventArgs is waiting for the next process, by asking it to go to another process, u will get this error.

So if the listener is a server, when the client tries to send, I would suggest u do a new connection and create a new SocketAsyncEventArgs for it.

Comment: Hi C_Rance, it's fine for establishing new connections, it's when I'm trying to send a packet out but you're probably right in that the SocketAsyncEventArgs is still processing the previous send when I try to send another one.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to call SAEA.AcceptSocket.EndAccept(...) first to end the async connection process or SAEA.AcceptSocket.EndSend(...) to end the previous sending

Comment: When you say end does it abort or complete? Cause I wouldn't want any packets to not be sent.

Comment: EndSend(..) will complete the operation and send the data

Comment: EndAccept is only used in pair with BeginAccept, not with AcceptAsync or the SocketAsyncEventArgs object.